# What does って時によ mean when used like this?

Tags: readings, reading-comprehension

君は他にも誰かと秘密を共有しているのか?

あ?誰かとって。。。もしかして彼達に嫉妬してるのか?

別にっ。。。するわけないだろう！　嫉妬なんて

スネんなよ。これからするって時によ

In the first like the girlfriend wonders how many people other than her and their friends know his secret.

To which the boyfriend replies... "Who else? Could it be you are jealous"?

And the character answers... "No I'm not jealous" but she's blatantly lying.

To which the boy friend replies "Don't sulk."

However, what does これからするって時によ mean here? "Is it something I'm going to do at times after this/from now on?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last line is a 倒置文, and the original sentence is:

> これからするって時に(よ)、スネんなよ。
>
> Don't sulk when it's time to do (it).

Where "do it" refers to the thing those two people are going to do. You know the story, so I believe you know what it is. This って is という, and よ is a filler/sentence-end particle.